# iOS SaaS Storage Subscriptions

Tags: ios, saas, in-app-subscription

I have been working on an application that will offer a similar subscription service to Evernote where we charge for monthly storage instead of content.

The issue I quickly ran into is the following:
When a user purchases a subscription, I can retrieve the receipt to check if the user has an active subscription and I can update how much storage they have left on the database.

Example: 6/10 GB left.

The problem with this is that if the user creates another account, the app will retrieve the same receipt (linked to apple ID) that confirms the user is subscribed and since it is a new account, it will allow the user to just use another 10 GB of space.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I'd recommend to tie current account and receipt on yours backend.

Comment: You need to link the purchase identifier of the receipt with the user in your back end and prevent the user from creating a second account and/or applying that subscription to the new account.

Comment: Yeah but how exactly would you do that? I can't really prevent a user from creating a new account and the subscription is linked to the Apple ID, not the user account linked to my SaaS. My best guess would be to create a section with all receipt IDs and the accounts they have been linked to. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: If you use a service like RevenueCat they can handle this for you, but yes, the basic idea is that you need to save all of the original transaction identifiers in your database and if the one in the receipt the new user is using is already associated with a user you either transfer the subscription to the new user or reject the new user